# Regex inside VIM to reuse part of the string and replace the other

Tags: regex

honestly bemused and I didn't expect to be asking this but here goes.

In side VIM, and only VIM, I want to perform a **global** search and replace. My target text is:

```
51099   analgesic
43045   analgesic
70145   analgesic
52338   analgesic
41214
55309
34373
47003
50659
51327
```

This goes on for several thousand lines. For all those lines that do not end "\tanalgesic" (notice the tab), I would like to retain the number and insert "\tanalgesic". I've tried several ways, none of which works (obviously).

Outside of VIM (in a general regex checker), [0-9]+$ finds all instances of **"one or more digits and the end of the line"**. Within VIM, this does not work (:/ will have been added to represent moving into command mode then "/" for a search). I'm so baffled by why this should be the case.

Although this does not work, I expect the solution is going to look similar:

```
:%s/[0-9]+$/(1)\tanalgesic/g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use for example vim very magic mode with `\v`

Use `\1` for a backreference to group 1.

```
:%s/\v(\d+$)/\1\tanalgesic/g
```

The command without very magic mode, with escaped parenthesis for the group, and the escaped plus sign for the quantifier:

```
%s/\([0-9]\+$\)/\1\tanalgesic/g
|  |      |     |             |
|  |      |     |             ^ All occurrences 
|  |      |     ^^ Backreference to group 1
|  |      ^^ Escaped plus sign
|  ^^ Escaped parenthesis for group 1
^ Substitute in whole file
```

Output

```
51099    analgesic
43045    analgesic
70145    analgesic
52338    analgesic
41214    analgesic
55309    analgesic
34373    analgesic
47003    analgesic
50659    analgesic
51327    analgesic
```

See http://vimregex.com/ for more information.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Honestly, I was struggling with this. A bit embarrassing.

Comment: @AnthonyNash Not at all, glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A very specific regex that match exactly what stated at first post is:

```
:%s/\(^\(\(.*analgesic.*\)\@!.\)*$\)/\1\tanalgesic
```

This part `^\(\(.*analgesic.*\)\@!.\)*$` match all lines that not contains `analgesic` word.